# How to use regex to select a column data

Tags: regex, python-re

---

How to fetch each data individually using regex?
when I run a command bjobs  i.e, bjobs 24634, I get the below data.

```
JOBID   USER  JOB_NAME  SUBMIT_TIME  START_TIME      RUN_TIME   
24634  xyz   abc     Aug 22 17:10    Aug 22 21:47   01:30:19
```

---

```py
pattern = r"\d+\s(w+)\s+\w+" #matches user name
matches = re.findall(pattern,data)
       
for match in matches: 
    JOBID,USER,STAT = match.split()
    print(f"Jobid: {JOBID}, User: {USER}")
```

I have tried using `findall` function but I'm not getting the expected output.

How to fetch data from both columns?

Comment: Maybe all you need is a findall with two groups? `re.findall(r"^(\w+)\s+(w+)", data, re.M)`

Comment: Actual command is bjobs <jobnumber> 
Everyday jobnumber changes.
And  format we get data in in two rows.

Comment: Ah, I see, the ``\`` was missing before the second `w`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
re.findall(r"^(\w+)\s+(\w+)", data, re.M)
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zODRba/1).